# How to Periodically Check Whether Data from API Has Changed

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, setinterval

I'm fetching weather data from OpenWeather API for a given location and want to check, every minute, whether that data is still current (and if not, change it).  I've used setInterval but the data doesn't seem to update every minute--here are the functions in question.

In the controller...

```
const controlStation = async function (station) {
  try {
    // Updates weather given station
    const weather = await model.updateWeather(station);

    // Periodically checks if weather data is current
    //  If not, updates weather
    let checkWeather = await model.checkWeather(station);
    setInterval(checkWeather, 1 * MINUTES);

    // Renders weather
    weatherView.render(model.stations[station], weather);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

controlStation("fbi");
```

In the model...

```
export const state = {};

export const stations = {
  fbi: {
    name: "fbi",
    city: "Sydney, Australia",
    coordinates: [-33.5346, 151.12],
  },
  kutx: {
    name: "kutx",
    city: "Austin, Texas, United States of America",
    coordinates: [30.1721, -97.4402],
  },
  cism: {
    name: "cism",
    city: "Montreal, Quebec, Canada",
    coordinates: [45.3023, -73.3644],
  },
};

export const updateWeather = async function (station) {
  try {
    const [lat, lng] = stations[station].coordinates;
    const url = `${API_WEATHER_URL}lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_WEATHER_KEY}&units=imperial`;

    const data = await fetch(url);
    const weather = await data.json();
    state.station = station;
    state.weather = weather;

    return weather;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

export const checkWeather = async function (station) {
  try {
    console.log("Checking weather!");
    const needsUpdate = false;

    const prev = state;
    console.log("prev", prev.weather);
    const cur = await updateWeather(state.station);
    console.log("cur", cur);

    if (
      prev.weather.wind.speed !== cur.wind.speed ||
      prev.weather.wind.dir !== cur.wind.dir ||
      prev.weather.main.temp !== cur.main.temp ||
      prev.weather.weather[0].description !== cur.weather[0].description
    ) {
      console.log("Changing now");
      needsUpdate = true;
    } else console.log(`They were same at ${Date.now()}`);

    return needsUpdate;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

I know I still need to do something if the weather data has changed and is different than what's in state, but I don't even see it making a new comparison through the checkWeather function every minute.

/////////////////
UPDATE--
I discovered that the issue was that async functions are incompatible with vanilla JS setInterval.  There's a node package for creating setInterval with an async callback function but I don't know Node yet so instead I grabbed this workaround off another StackOverflow answer.

```
async function execute1() {
      while (true) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2 * MINUTES));
        await model.checkWeather(station);
      }
    }

    execute1();
```

Now my program is successfully checking the results from a new API call to the data stored in state.  It recognizes when things have changed and when they haven't and now I'm going to update state when the weather conditions have changed.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Most weather APIs aren't updated that frequently. Depending on the API it could be a half hour or more until something changes from the last check.

Comment: Your declaration of `checkWeather` and subsequent use of it with `setInterval` does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: You would need to store information of the old data somewhere and use that to display. Then every minute make a new API call and compare the API return data with the data in your storage and if they are not the same, replace the old data with the new API data. If you want to create real-time functionality look into using websockets

Comment: @esqew, could you elaborate?

Comment: @SebastianGbudje, I'm storing data in state.  Am I not making a new API call with each checkWeather call (which calls updateWeather, which is an API call)?

Comment: @MaxMcCready In your controller, what do you *believe* `checkWeather` *is*, exactly? Have you debugged this piece of code and verified this belief? What do you believe is being passed to `setInterval` in the line immediately following?

Comment: A couple things stand out to me. There seems to be some syntax issue in your `checkweather` function. There is no opening curly brace for the `else`. Next, is what does the `needsUpdate` do? You return it at the end but I can't seem to see where it's being used. Why not just call the update weather function instead of returning `needsUpdate`?

Comment: @esqew Hi! Thank you for your help.  I successfully debugged it as shown in the update to my post above.  The issue was that setInterval doesn't work well with async functions called inside of it.

Comment: @SebastianGbudje Thank you for your help Sebastian!  I successfully debugged it as shown in my update above.